# Drawing custom oval and rectangle XML shape as buttom background

Tags: android, xml, shapes, layer-list

I want to create custom button background that look like this:

[image]

I can't use `corners` attribute in rectangle `shape` because its rounds only the corner and the middle of the left side is straight or whenver I set too much value to that attribute it looks like that.
[image]

I hope that i can combine 2 shapes (oval and rectangle) like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085689/4776020) but whenever I try to rotate that layer-list it doesnt look like wanted shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
             <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/test"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
              />
```

and `@drawable/test` will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-30dp"
        android:bottom="-30dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

**Note:**
I know this is not the best solution. But for now this can help.
and if you want to increase the width of Button then change the below  attributes accordingly to fit your need.

```
android:top="-30dp"
android:bottom="-30dp"
```

and the `result` will look like this:

[image]

Comment: it worked well thank you. I have another small task with it do you know how to round a right corners a little bit? (around 6 dp should work)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below as drawable file and set as background to button. For Curvy edges, you can increase decrease radius from below.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#2b74d2"
        android:startColor="#2b74d2"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```